# PHP cURL https not working on new VPS

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https

I have recently bought a VPS hosting solution to run my site and scripts on. Before, on shared hosting, a PHP cURL request would work to a https url, however, now on the VPS I find it just hangs forever (until the script times out).

Anyone know what the problem could be? I've done some searching, but I don't need to verify the CA cert for the url in the same code I ran on the shared host, so I don't see why I should have to verify it on this server.

Additionally - I've got cURL SSL and curlwrapper PHP modules installed. I'm guessing that there is another module that I need to install for it to work?

I'm managing it via WHM.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Providing your cURL code would be helpful.
What is the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, deactivate SSL. It already happened to me, and this is what i did:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Don't forgot to check `openssl.so` or `openssl.dll` extensions too.

**This will also allow Man In The Middle attacks, it's not recommended.**

Comment: This allows for MITM attacks.

Comment: This is true. I'll update the answer to let people know about. Thanks for remember me about that.